# How to get first 2 characters in a comma separated string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

How to get first 2 characters  in a comma separated string. It should be in capital letter and add _ (underscore) between the 2 characters using Javascript?

countries: "Afghanistan, Albania, Germany"

And I want output as below:
**AF_AL_GE**
How can I get this output ?

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string by `", "`, map through it and get the first two characters with `slice`, join it all with an underscore, then make it uppercase:

```js
const countries = "Afghanistan, Albania, Germany"
const output = countries
  .split(", ")
  .map(i => i.slice(0, 2))
  .join("_")
  .toUpperCase()

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split string to array by ", ". Next map the subsisting and convert it to uppercase, Finally join the array with "_"

```js
const countries = "Afghanistan, Albania, Germany";
const countryCodeString = countries
  .split(", ") 
  .map(country => country.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase())
  .join("_"); 
console.log(countryCodeString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```js
    const input = "Afghanistan, Albania, Germany";
    const combineStr = (str) => str.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(([a,b]) => a+b).join("_").toUpperCase();
    
    console.log(combineStr(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this requirement by using `RegEx` to match the countries and then implement the data manipulation.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input string
const countries = "Afghanistan, Albania, Germany";

// Getting formatted string with the help of 'String.match()' method along with 'Array.map()'
const formattedString = countries.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)
.map(country => country.substr(0, 2).toUpperCase());

// Output
console.log(formattedString.join('_'));
```